# Error while installing statsmodels for python2.7 in windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels

I installed statsmodels.
`pip install statsmodels`
but there is an error

```
error: Command "C:\Users\GL\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
 C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- 
/DNDEBUG -DCYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=0 -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local
\temp\pip-buil-env-tqipb2\Lib\site-package\numpy\core\inclide -Ic:
\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-env-tqipb2
\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -Ic:\python27\include 
-Ic:\python27\PC /Tcstatsmodels/tsa/_stl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\
Release\statsmodels/tsa/_stl.obj" failed with exit status 2
```

````
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>pip install statsmodels
Collecting statsmodels
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/1c/b83f6a4632b502a20b0
f83bc5c25ebfa03eebd00efe9b45fcdcde1a0ab40/statsmodels-0.11.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
 statsmodels) (1.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (fro
m statsmodels) (1.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.21 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (fr
om statsmodels) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
 statsmodels) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (fro
m pandas>=0.21->statsmodels) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-pa
ckages (from pandas>=0.21->statsmodels) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from patsy>
=0.5->statsmodels) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: statsmodels
  Running setup.py install for statsmodels ...
copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_ 
granger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\
tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_
granger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\
tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_
inst_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_
inst_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_
ir.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results

    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_
lagorder.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_r
esults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cisli_
Sigmau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_res
ults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_di
ag.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results

    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_fc
5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_gr
anger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\te
sts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_gr
anger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\te
sts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_in
st_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests
\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_in
st_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests
\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_ir
.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_la
gorder.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_res
ults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cis_Si
gmau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resul
ts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_dia
g.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_fc5
.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_gra
nger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_gra
nger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_ins
t_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\
JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_ins
t_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\
JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_ir.
txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_lag
order.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resu
lts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ci_Sig
mau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_result
s
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co.txt
 -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo.t
xt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_d
iag.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_result
s
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_f
c5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results

    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_g
ranger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\t
ests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_g
ranger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\t
ests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_i
nst_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\test
s\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_i
nst_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\test
s\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_i
r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_l
agorder.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_re
sults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_colo_S
igmau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resu
lts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos.tx
t -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo.
txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
diag.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resul
ts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
fc5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_result
s
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
granger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\
tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
granger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\
tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
inst_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
inst_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
ir.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results

    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
lagorder.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_r
esults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_coslo_
Sigmau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_res
ults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_di
ag.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results

    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_fc
5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_gr
anger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\te
sts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_gr
anger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\te
sts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_in
st_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests
\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_in
st_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests
\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_ir
.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_la
gorder.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_res
ults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_cos_Si
gmau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resul
ts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_dia
g.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_fc5
.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_gra
nger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_gra
nger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_ins
t_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\
JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_ins
t_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\
JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_ir.
txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_lag
order.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resu
lts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_co_Sig
mau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_result
s
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc.txt
 -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs.tx
t -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_di
ag.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results

    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_fc
5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_gr
anger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\te
sts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_gr
anger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\te
sts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_in
st_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests
\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_in
st_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests
\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_ir
.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_la
gorder.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_res
ults
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_ncs_Si
gmau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resul
ts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_dia
g.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_fc5
.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_gra
nger_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_gra
nger_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tes
ts\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_ins
t_causality_dp_r.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\
JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_ins
t_causality_r_dp.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\
JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_ir.
txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_lag
order.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_resu
lts
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_results\vecm_e6_jmulti_nc_Sig
mau.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\JMulTi_result
s
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\Matlab_results\test_coint.csv -> bui
ld\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\Matlab_results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\vars_results.npz -> build\li
b.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\e1.dat -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\e2.dat -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\e3.dat -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\e4.dat -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\e5.dat -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    copying statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results\e6.dat -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-2.7\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\tests\results
    UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels/_version.py
    set build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\statsmodels/_version.py to '0.11.0'
    running build_ext
    _stl.c
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(5331) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '
Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(5434) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '
Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(5609) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '
Py_ssize_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(5732) : error C2065: 'NAN' : undeclared identifier
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6119) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '
Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6129) : warning C4013: 'isnan' undefined; assuming ex
tern returning int
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6274) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '
Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6432) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssiz
e_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6441) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssiz
e_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6453) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '
Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(6943) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssiz
e_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(7126) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssiz
e_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(7319) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssiz
e_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    statsmodels/tsa/_stl.c(7671) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssiz
e_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    error: Command "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visua
l C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -D
CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=0 -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-qjfz0h\Li
b\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip
-build-env-qjfz0h\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -Ic:\python27\includ
e -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcstatsmodels/tsa/_stl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
\statsmodels/tsa/_stl.obj" failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-obef4w\\statsmodels\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admin
\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-eqbcfo\install-record.txt --single-version-extern
ally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local
\temp\pip-install-obef4w\statsmodels\
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.```
````

Comment: The actual error message will be found somewhere above this.

Comment: Maybe this error comes when it Shows that setup.py installing for statsmodels.After that above commands are shown in cmd

Comment: Add your error message to the question, it is not readable in the comments.

Comment: I have added the error message in my question.please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

statsmodels does not support Python 2.7. The most recent release supports 3.5 or later while the master branch requires 3.6. If you must use 2.7 you might need to pin the version to 0.10.2.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my issue. It has been installed successfully